# How do I deploy a charm when it is shown in the charm store but the cli reports it's not found?

Tags: juju

I am trying to deploy Marco Ceppi's `discourse` charm from [this link](http://jujucharms.com/~marcoceppi/precise/discourse) however running "juju deploy discourse" yields the following output:

```
pgrace@shaman:~$ juju deploy discourse
2013-02-26 20:49:05,541 INFO Searching for charm cs:precise/discourse in charm store
2013-02-26 20:49:06,076 ERROR Error processing 'cs:precise/discourse': entry not found
```

I feel as though I'm missing something.  Executing `juju deploy lp:~marcoceppi/charms/precise/discourse/trunk` yields this result:

```
pgrace@shaman:~$ juju deploy lp:~marcoceppi/charms/precise/discourse/trunk
2013-02-26 20:50:25,781 ERROR Bad charm URL 'lp:~marcoceppi/charms/precise/discourse/trunk': invalid schema (URL inferred from 'lp:~marcoceppi/charms/precise/discourse/trunk')
```

Is there a certain syntax to loading charms not in the charm store?

Comment: I've updated the readme to reflect the proper way to currently deploy Discourse since I don't plan on landing this in the store until upstream comes out with a solid 1.0 release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the README is written as if the charm is in the store, but it's not yet:

```
juju deploy cs:~marcoceppi/precise/discourse
```

Will do what you want in the meantime. This isn't very obvious or user friendly, so I filed [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/charmworld/+bug/1133822).